# How do i set .net MVC4 application to use azure storage instead of sql server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I would like to use .new built-in security and authentication method in MVC4 work with azure storage, the meaning is, instead of creating users on SQL database i want to create them on Azure storage, same thing about the login process.
what do you think? is it possible?

as far as i read i get the feeling that it Requires Full SQL Server for default cases
The default, and most fully featured providers ASP.NET Membership providers (SQL Membership Provider, SQL Role Provider, SQL Profile Provider) require full SQL Server. They depend on stored procedure support, and they rely on SQL Server cache dependencies, they depend on agents for clean up and maintenance. So the main SQL Server based providers don't work well on SQL Server CE, won't work out of the box on SQL Azure, etc.

[link]http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                try
                {
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use it with Azure table & blob storage take a look at complete source code [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Windows-Azure-ASPNET-03d5dc14) however there are some [trade-off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083328/asp-net-membership-provider) to use with storage.