# SessionStateProvider using Blob/Table for Window Azure

Tags: c#, azure, cloud

Now I'm going to use the SessionStateProvider class from the [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Windows-Azure-ASPNET-03d5dc14) provided by Mircosoft into production .

1. In addition to clearing used session records from the blob, what
   else do I need to take into consideration before using it in live site?
2. In the sample, SessionStateStoreData is serialized and stored in the blob. Instead,  can I store in one of the columns of the table? What is the pros and cons of this approach?
3. While clearing the unnecessary session in the table and blob, what is the best and safest way to clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the table based session state provider is not suitable to be used in production for a site.  The hint is that Microsoft called it a sample.  My main reason for this is that it doesn't deal with [locking session data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940891/asp-net-mvc-azure-error-accessing-the-data-store/3952346#3952346) if there are several requests for the same session in a short period of time.

Comment: Thanks..knight. In addition to locking problem, are there any other issues I need to address?

Comment: Other than the fact that it will just error on you, I think you've already mentioned al of the issues (mainly that sessions aren't expired out of the blobs/tables)